# What does Degit exactly stand for?

Tags: degit

I have searched thoroughly for the full form of Degit, but could not find it anywhere.
What does it exactly stand for?

Please provide any link to further read about how/why it was developed.

Comment: https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit, a _straightforward project scaffolding_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intended meaning of degit must be `depth git`.
It is a package which performs tasks very similar to what `git clone --depth 1` does and the intention is that it should make copies of git repositories.

You can read further on this in [degit's documentation provided in npmjs site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/degit?activeTab=readme#wait-isnt-this-just-git-clone---depth-1-).

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure I understood your question but I think Degit is meant to be `de-` (prefix meaning *to undo*, like in *deactivate*) and `-git` (version control). In other words, to download a project that uses [git](https://git-scm.com/) for version control, but without git (basically without the `.git` folder).

Probably the most accurate description comes from the [official git repository](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit):

> degit makes copies of git repositories. When you run `degit some-user/some-repo`, it will find the latest commit on https://github.com/some-user/some-repo and download the associated tar file to `~/.degit/some-user/some-repo/commithash.tar.gz` if it doesn't already exist locally. (This is much quicker than using `git clone`, because you're not downloading the entire git history.)

Also, if you still do not understand the reasoning for Degits existence I suggest reading the [Wait, isn't this just git clone?](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit#wait-isnt-this-just-git-clone---depth-1) section.